# Rspec stub_chain with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, stub

I know I can do the following:

```
Foo.stub_chain(:bar, :baz).with(:marflar).with(:quux)
```

And this stubs out a call to

```
Foo.bar(:marflar).baz(:quux)
```

But what would I do if I wanted to remove the argument supplied to `baz`? i.e.

```
Foo.bar(:marflar).baz
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the a call without any argument, you can use `with(no_args)`. If you do not care for arguments, use `with(any_args)`. There are [more matchers available](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments).

So to match this:

```
Foo.bar(:marflar).baz
```

Use this:

```
# expect no arguments
Foo.stub_chain(:bar, :baz).with(:marflar).with(no_args)
# expect 0 or any arguments
Foo.stub_chain(:bar, :baz).with(:marflar).with(any_args)
```